# not component rendering after animation ( fetch data ) in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, loading

I'm working on a Star wars project. I added an animation when capturing the data. But once you pull the data, the component does not render again. Continuous animation remains active. What am I missing? Thank you in advance, everyone, good evening.

Note: This github project link : https://github.com/kasim444/Javascript-Camp-2019/tree/master/challenges/star-wars-app.

Finally, I am open to your suggestions if there is my development.

```js
class MovieDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    title:null,
    episode_id:null,
    opening_crawl:null,
    director:null,
    producer:null,
    release_date:null,
    characters:[],
    loading:true,
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const titleSearch = this.props.match.params.title;
    let characterNames = [];
    const movieDetail = await  axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/?search=${encodeURI(titleSearch)}`);
    const charactersFetchLinks = movieDetail.data.results[0].characters.slice(0, 10);
    const promisesData = await charactersFetchLinks.map( link => axios.get(link) );
    axios.all(promisesData).then(value => {
      value.map(val => characterNames.push(val.data.name) );
      const {title, episode_id, opening_crawl, director, producer, release_date} = movieDetail.data.results[0];
      this.setState({ title, episode_id, opening_crawl, director, producer, release_date, characters: characterNames, loading: false });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const movieId = this.state.episode_id;
    const loading = this.state;
     return (
        loading ?
        <Loading /> :
        <div>
          <main className="movieBg">
            <DetailHeader imgLink={moviesImageLinks[movieId-1]} />
            <MovieContent imgLink={moviesImageLinks[movieId-1]} movieInfo={this.state} />
          </main>
          <FeaturedMovies />
        </div>
       );
    }
  }
  export default MovieDetails;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not destructured the property correctly.

```
 const movieId = this.state.episode_id;
 const loading = this.state;
```

Should be:

```
 const { episode_id, loading } = this.state
```

Loading will always be true since state is always defined.

Comment: Your suggestion worked. thank you. I normally do Destruct but I missed it because I was coding fast.

Comment: @KasimŞEN glad I could help. If you could mark it as the correct answer that would be awesome 

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace

```
const loading = this.state;
```

By:

```
 const loading = this.state.loading;
```

Comment: Thank you buddy. A small detail that I missed 